# Adding a space after a specific character in a string

Tags: java, string, char, stringbuilder

Basically, `(dog)(cat)(mouse)` needs to be `(dog) (cat) (mouse)`.

My attempted code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(dog)(cat)(mouse)");

for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i ++)
{
   if (sb.charAt(i) == ')')
   {
      sb.insert(i, ' ');
   }
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

But I'm getting some sort of "Java heap space" error

Comment: Where does `sb.insert(i, ' ');` insert the space?

Comment: This is partly because the one the loop encounters the first `)`, it adds a space BEFORE it, so on the next iteration, it will find another `)` (creating something like `" )"`).  You could see this if you add a `System.out.println` after each iteration

Comment: @sotirios After the found index of the closing parentheses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think it happens the *first* time it encounters the `)` but you have the idea right.

Comment: @soong True, I jumped to the last one cause it was obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
String string = "(dog)(cat)(mouse)";
string = string.replace(")(", ") (");
```

This replaces all occurrences of "`)(`" with "`) (`".

But if you want to do it your way, the fix will be to increment `i` using `i++;` right before you insert, since you are inserting a space before your bracket, not after it.

Comment: This is just me, but I really don't like modifying the loop variable within loops, it can really hard to debug if problems arise, but that's me :P

Comment: Until you have to replace `A` with `AA` and it blows up for the same reason as the question. There's no problem with changing loop variables within loops, especially if you're advancing them. But to each their own :)

Comment: As I said, it's just me - I don't like doing it because it's unobvious (and easy to miss), bit like placing a `return` statement in the middle of your method.  It's really easy to miss and lose the context of what's going on. Don't say you shouldn't do it, just that it creeps me out and has it's own set of issues ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
(dog)(ca
01234567
```

You invoke

```
  sb.insert(i, ' ');
```

with `i == 4`. `insert` takes everything at the current offset shifts it right by 1 and inserts the given characters. So

```
(dog )(ca
012345678
```

Then you loop again, and now `i++` becomes 5, where there is the previous `)`, so you do the same thing and add a space before it.

```
(dog  )(ca
0123456789
```

You keep repeating this until you run out of heap space.

Add the space after the `)`.

```
 sb.insert(i + 1, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, when the loop encounters the first `)` character, it inserts a space at the exact position of `i` (where the `)` currently is), this effectively adds the space BEFORE the `)` character.

On the next loop, it will encounter the same `)` character and the process repeats until you run out of memory...

Instead, you want to  use `i + 1` to insert the space AFTER the `)` character, for example...

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(dog)(cat)(mouse)");

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == ')') {
            sb.insert(i + 1, ' ');
        }
    }

    String result = sb.toString().trim();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Which outputs

```
(dog) (cat) (mouse)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the space after the bracket (i+1). The reason for the heap error was that you were increasing the length of sb overtime you did an insert.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(dog)(cat)(mouse)");
    int length =  sb.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
    {
       if (sb.charAt(i) == ')')
       {
         sb.insert(i+1, " ");
       }
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```